# USB Ethernet Connecting

Tags: wireless

I shared internet connection through *USB tethering* from my android device. But my Ubuntu 22.04 says **USB Ethernet connecting** for a long time. But not connected yet. How to solve this?

Comment: It is all about settings in your phone.

Comment: May be. When I share it on other OS like windows it works well. I think problem is not with my device